# htaccess redirect folder to another folder (download)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, download

How do i redirect with .htaccess

http://www.mysite.net/folder 1/category/1.zip

to

http://www.mysite.net/folder1/category/1.zip

?

NOTE: folder 1 contain space between

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Techinically, you should never even use a space in a folder name, so I refuse to answer this. However, in your quest, keep in mind browsers send the request as example.com/folder%201

Comment: May I ask why you feel the need for a space?

Comment: the folder was not created by me, i just give a help.
i know we have to use "-" or "_".

thank you

Comment: Please don't spam. Flagged.